# Why has 14.04 LTS no static libraries in some packages?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, libraries, udev

These are the udev development packages for the last three Ubuntu LTS releases.

- [File list of package libudev-dev in lucid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/amd64/libudev-dev/filelist)
- [File list of package libudev-dev in precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libudev-dev/filelist)
- [File list of package libudev-dev in trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libudev-dev/filelist)

The last link is the package for 14.04 and it doesn't contain the `*.a` file for static linkage. Why is it missing and how do I get it?