# Where can I find the static udev libraries for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, udev

I am trying to build an executable using the USB static library which in turn needs the UDEV static library.  I have the libusb-1.0.a file but cannot locate the libudev.a file for linking.  I have searched the forums for an answer to this but there does not seem be any responses.  This includes a post to this forum at:

[Why has 14.04 LTS no static libraries in some packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546414/why-has-14-04-lts-no-static-libraries-in-some-packages)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 7 months old, but I still wanted to give it a try since "libudev.a" is missing from 14.04 distribution.  I really want to skip building one locally via systemd repo if there is an alternative from Ubuntu side.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there isn't. None of the Ubuntu nor Debian packages found online make a mention of libudev.a at all. Only the shared library's available.